# Close ANTLR4 CharStream (Java Runtime) - OutOfMemoryException

Tags: java, antlr

I am currently trying to parse a big file (~700k lines) with ANTLR using Java Runtime. The file is too big and the parsing leads to an "Out of Memory" exception (after having more than 8GB of RAM assigned).

Since I do not care about parsing everything together, I was able to split the file into several files containing a few functions each. I am now running several threads in order to parse each of the obtained files.

Here is the run() function of my runnable for every thread:

```
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Starting to parse file " + this.filename);
    try {
        org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStream stream = CharStreams.fromFileName(this.filename, Charset.defaultCharset());
        CPP14Lexer lexer = new CPP14Lexer(stream);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        CPP14Parser parser = new CPP14Parser(tokens);
        ParseTree tree = parser.translationunit();
        lexer = null;
        tokens = null;
        parser = null;
        tree = null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    TheParser.current_temp_file.decrementAndGet();
    System.out.println("Finished parsing file " + this.filename);
}
```

**Here is my problem**: the threads run well. I run them 3 by three (using the "TheParser.current_temp_file" static atomic integer) in order to avoid the memory issue. However, the threads do never completely terminate. Thus, after executing, they are still alive, and the memory keeps on increasing.

I think the problem probably comes from the CharStream, which is never closed. However, there is no such method in the org.antlrv4.runtime.CharStream class.

Do you know where the problem comes from and how I could handle it?

Thank you!

Comment: I wonder why there is no `close` method. I guess all you can do is set `stream` to `null`.

Comment: I tried this, and unfortunately, it doesn't help...

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed no `close` method, because `CharStream` is a general interface and `CharStreams` which builds the `CharStream` instances for you can build many different implementations from many sources. For some of them (e.g. `CharStreams.fromString()`) there's nothing to close at all, for others you're supposed to close the underlying stream directly.

From the [source code](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/CharStreams.java) it looks like the file is read into memory and then closed within `CharStreams` even before you get hold of the `CharStream` instance.

I recommend you investigate instead of guessing. Is it still crashing on memory? Run your application with [`-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/clopts-139448.html#gbzrr) and investigate the resulting memory dump. Are the threads not exiting? Use a profiler (e.g. [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/)) to see where the threads are getting stuck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get an `Exception in thread "Thread-16" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` after a few threads have been created and terminated (supposedly). I already investigated with Process Hacker. The process apparently keeps handles to the new threads, but this should not even be a problem because the run function is finished right? I also don't know why the handles are kept since I have no variable storing the threads... I will try to investigate more with a profiler :)

Comment: Get a heap dump and find why the data is not GCed. I've had most success with [Eclispe Memory Analyzer plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/memory-analyzer-0), if you use Eclipse you might want to try that one.